# Confirmation of an answer of a question on Boolean Algebra

Tags: boolean-algebra

Here are the solution I have worked out. Is it correct?

> Given $C + BC'$:
>
> 1. $C + B' + C'$
> 2. $C + (B'+C')'$
> 3. $C + B + C$
> 4. $C (C + B + C)$.

Is the answer (2)?

Comment: $C+BC'=C+B$; this is equivalent to $C+B+C$, so $(3)$ is correct.

Answer (score 0):

$$Given: C + B\overline C = C (1 + B) + B\overline C = C + BC + B\overline C = C + B (C + \overline C) = B + C$$
$$1.\ C + \overline B + \overline C = \overline B + (C + \overline C) =  \overline B + 1 = 1$$
$$2.\ C + \overline {(\overline B + \overline C)} = C + BC = C (1 + B) = C$$
$$3.\  C + B + C =  B + C$$
$$4.\ C (C + B + C) = CC + BC + CC = C + BC + C = C (1 + B + 1) = C$$

Reduce them all and the answer has to be 3.

[Laws and Theorems of Boolean Algebra](http://www.mi.mun.ca/users/cchaulk/misc/boolean.htm)